# WPF Datagrid Binding Doesn't Update Until Clicking Row Header

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding

I have a datagrid that is bound to a List in the view model. The grid's contents don't update until I click on the row header. Clicking in various cells doesn't affect it. I have to click on the header.

This is the datagrid in the XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TransactionDetailsGrid" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Extended" IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TransactionDetailList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTransactionDetail}" GridLinesVisibility="None">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Account.AccountNumber}" Header="Account No." HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderStyleCenter}" Width="120" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Account.AccountName}" Header="Account Name" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderStyleCenter}" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Amount}"  Header="Amount" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderStyleCenter}" Width="120" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And this is from the view model:

```
public List<TransactionDetail> TransactionDetailList
{
    get { return this._transactionDetailList; }

    set
    {
        this._transactionDetailList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("TransactionDetailList");                
    }
}
```

This is the edit of one of the items, in the view model:

```
private void AddTransactionDetail()
{
    TransactionDetailViewModel viewModel = new TransactionDetailViewModel();

    MainWindowViewModel.ViewLoader.ShowDialog(viewModel);

    if (viewModel.TransactionDetail != null)
    {
        this.TransactionDetailList.Add(viewModel.TransactionDetail);
        RaisePropertyChanged("TransactionDetailList");
    }
}
```

After this runs, I can put a breakpoint on the getter of TransactionDetailList, and the collection has the item in it. However, the datagrid is empty. If I click on the header row, the item shows up in the grid.

I have the same issue when doing an edit.

I've done this successfully before, so I'm not sure what's different here. Am I missing something obvious? Why won't the grid show its contents until I click on the header row?

I just noticed something interesting. When I click on the grid header, the breakpoint in the TransactionDetailList getter doesn't get hit, but the data still shows up. So, it's like the grid has the info, it's just not showing it until the header is clicked.

After changing to use ObservableCollection, it worked. But now I'm having the same problem with the edit (grid doesn't update until clicking the header):

```
private void EditTransactionDetail()
{
    TransactionDetailViewModel viewModel = new TransactionDetailViewModel(this.SelectedTransactionDetail);

    MainWindowViewModel.ViewLoader.ShowDialog(new TransactionDetailViewModel(this.SelectedTransactionDetail));

    RaisePropertyChanged("TransactionDetailList");
}
```

Does my entity need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged? If I change the collection, and call RaisePropertyChanged, shouldn't that cause an update to the grid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that when you add or remove an item from the collection, the setter isn't called.  This means `INotifyPropertyChanged` isn't called, and the view has no way of knowing it needs to be refreshed.

WPF solves this by also supporting the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface.

Try using an `ObservableCollection<TransactionDetail>` instead of a `List<TransactionDetail>`.  `ObservableCollection<T>` is built in, and implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, so you won't have to do much to your code.

Also make sure that you continue to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your view model as you already have.  This way the view will be notified when you replace the entire collection (when the setter is called).

```
public ObservableCollection<TransactionDetail> TransactionDetailList
{
    get { return this._transactionDetailList; }

    set
    {
        this._transactionDetailList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("TransactionDetailList");                
    }
}
```

See:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx (although this isn't using MVVM style)

**Edit**:

Also, you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `TransactionDetail` too.  If you can't, wrap it in a class that does implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

If you don't implement it on `TransactionDetail`, than changes you make that don't impact the list, but do impact properties on a `TransactionDetail` instance, won't show in the UI until you somehow refresh the whole list.

If you tried to fix this by calling `RaisePropertyChanged` on the list property, then your UI thinks the entire list (and hence the whole set of UI objects) needs to be thrown out and updated.  This will kill your performance and make your app sluggish.

Comment: So, when I change an item in the list, should this line cause the datagrid to update, showing the updated item within it? RaisePropertyChanged("TransactionDetailList");

Comment: @Bob: Nope.  Your setter works like any other property setter does in the language.  It only gets called when you replace the entire `TransactionDetailList`.  This isn't terribly helpful in the case of a UI, which is exactly why they created `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: @Bob: Oh, wait, you mean the final one in your question?  No, you shouldn't tell the UI that the whole list is changing when you're only changing the values of one of the properties of one of the items that *happens* to be stored in the list.  This will totally kill your perf.  Instead, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `TransactionDetail` class, too.

Comment: But does it matter if the setter gets called? If I'm explicitly calling RaisePropertyChanged("TransactionDetailList"), shouldn't that cause a binding update?

Comment: Okay, that's what I'm trying now: implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the TransactionDetail class. Thank you for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Bob: Glad we got to the bottom of the problem you were having.  This stuff definitely has a learning curve to it :)

Comment: I just implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on TransactionDetail, and everything is working as expected. Maybe next time I shouldn't try to shortcut the process. :o)

Answer (score 2):

If you want you grid to update the moment you change the IEnumerable list it is bound to, make it a type of list that implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx). A built in data type that has this is the [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) ([also here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx)). So if you make your property look like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<TransactionDetail> TransactionDetailList
{
    get { return this._transactionDetailList; }

    set
    {
        this._transactionDetailList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("TransactionDetailList");                
    }
}
```

your grid will automatically pick up any items you add or remove from the list.
Effectively what you are doing here is notifying when the *list* has changed (i.e. the list reference), but you are not notifying when the *contents* of the list have changed.

Comment: I changed to an ObservableCollection and the grid is updating. I've done this before by just using List<T>, and it worked.

Comment: @Bob: You probably called the setter and replaced the entire list.  Either that, or you did your updates before the list was queried to begin with.